# Memory usage and minimizing

Tags: c++, memory, graphics, memory-leaks, openscenegraph

We have a fairly graphical intensive application that uses the FOX toolkit and OpenSceneGraph, and of course C++.  I notice that after running the application for some time, it seems there is a memory leak.  However when I minimize, a substantial amount of memory appears to be freed (as witnessed in the Windows Task Manager).  When the application is restored, the memory usage climbs but plateaus to an amount less than what it was before the minimize.

Is this a huge indicator that we have a nasty memory leak?  Or might this be something with how Windows handles graphical applications?  I'm not really sure what is going on.

Comment: This might be a memory leak. See if you can detect it using some software like [IBM Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) or [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is simply memory caching. When you call free()/delete()/delete, most implementations won't actually return this memory to the OS. They will keep it to be returned in a much faster fashion the next time you request it. When your application is minimized, they will free this memory because you won't be requesting it anytime soon.

It's unlikely that you have an actual memory leak. Task Manager is not particularly accurate, and there's a lot of behaviour that can change the apparent amount of memory that you're using- even if you released it properly. You need to get an actual memory profiler to take a look if you're still concerned.

Also, yes, Windows does a lot of things when minimizing applications. For example, if you use Direct3D, there's a device loss. There's thread timings somethings. Windows is designed to give the user the best experience in a single application at a time and may well take extra cached/buffered resources from your application to do it.

Comment: Ah thanks for the expanation.  I was hoping it wasn't an issue on our end.

Answer (score 1):

No, there effect you are seeing means that your platform releases resources when it's not visible (good thing), and that seems to clear some cached data, which is not restored after restoring the window.

Doing this may help you find memory leaks. If the minimum amount of memory (while minimized) used by the app grows over time, that would suggest a leak.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the working set size of your program.  The sum of the virtual memory pages of your program that are actually in RAM.  When you minimize your main window, Windows assumes the user won't be interested in the program for a while and aggressively trims the working set.  Copying the pages in RAM to the paging file and chucking them out, making room for the other process that the user is likely to start or to switch to.

This number will also go down automatically when the user starts another program that needs a lot of RAM.  Windows chucks out your pages to make room for this program.  It picks pages that your program hasn't used for a while, making it likely that this doesn't affect the perf of your program much.

When you switch back to your program, Windows needs to swap pages back into RAM.  But this is on-demand, it only pages-in pages that your program actually uses.  Which will normally be less than what it used before, no need to swap the initialization code of your program back in for example.

Needless to say perhaps, the number has absolutely nothing to do with the memory usage of your program, it is merely a statistical number.

Private bytes would be a better indicator for a memory leak.  Taskmgr doesn't show that, SysInternals' ProcMon tool does.  It still isn't a great indicator because that number also includes any blocks in the heap that were freed by your program and were added to the list of free blocks, ready to be re-used.  There is no good way to measure actual memory in use, read the small print for the HeapWalk() API function for the kind of trouble that causes.

The memory and heap manager in Windows are far too sophisticated to draw conclusions from the available numbers.  Use a leak detection tool, like the VC debug allocator (crtdbg.h).